# Distinguishing between local Windows users created with or without an email address

Tags: windows, scripting, registry, local, user-accounts

I'm working on a script to identify local Windows user accounts and determine whether they were created with or without an associated email address. In the Windows Settings app, local users without email addresses are labeled as "Local Account" below their usernames.

while creating a user, windows ask to provide email address, we can skip that and create a local account, i need all usernames who create like that

Comment: "Local Windows users created with an email address" _ I think those are not in fact local users.  But this question is tricky. It assumes a dichotomy which I don't think exists when you include domain-attached Windows clients.

Comment: "I'm working on a script" - batch? Powershell? WSH? Something else?